# set onclicklistener for button inside listview and itemclicklistener to listview both android

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I am creating a customlistview which contains buttons and edittext and textview.
I have added onclicklistener to the buttons. also I want the itemclicklistener of listview should  work. the buttons are for changing the value inside the edittext. and onitemclicklistener is for sending data to next activity.
But when I add onclicklistener to button the itemclicklistener of the listview does not work.
I have tried changing buttons to imageview still it doesnt work.Also I tried adding property focusable="false" for button but the activity gets forced close when focusable="false" is added.

help me to achieve this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any row item of list contains `Focusable` or `Clickable` view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work. Check [descendantFocusability](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3adescendantFocusability).

row item must be having param like

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Add this line in your `list_item.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

// your other Button and Other widget here

</LinearLayout>
```